# Making a GET call on an OAuth protected URL, part 2

Tags: objective-c, ios, oauth

I've been trying to get a basic OAuth interaction working without success. There are certainly similar questions already posed on SO, but most of them have no replies. I'm getting pretty desperate here, so I'm just going to start by posting my entire code:

```
// OAuth parameters
NSString *oauthNonce = [self genRandStringLength:20];
NSString *oauthSignatureMethod = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"HMAC-SHA1"];
time_t oauthTimeStamp = (time_t) [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];

// generate OAuth signature
NSString *encodedUrlString = [self urlEncode:urlString];

NSString *oauthParameters = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"oauth_consumer_key=%@",oauthConsumerKey];
oauthParameters = [oauthParameters stringByAppendingFormat:@"&oauth_nonce=%@",oauthNonce];
oauthParameters = [oauthParameters stringByAppendingFormat:@"&oauth_signature_method=%@",oauthSignatureMethod];
oauthParameters = [oauthParameters stringByAppendingFormat:@"&oauth_timestamp=%d",oauthTimeStamp];
oauthParameters = [oauthParameters stringByAppendingFormat:@"&oauth_token=%@",oauthAccessToken];
oauthParameters = [oauthParameters stringByAppendingFormat:@"&oauth_version=1.0"];
NSString *oauthEncodedParameters = [self urlEncode:oauthParameters];

NSString *oauthBaseString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"GET&%@&%@",encodedUrlString,oauthEncodedParameters];

NSString *oauthKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@&%@", oauthConsumerSecret, oauthAccessTokenSecret];
NSString *oauthEncodedKey = [self urlEncode:oauthKey];

OAHMAC_SHA1SignatureProvider *provider = [[OAHMAC_SHA1SignatureProvider alloc] init];
NSString *oauthSignature = [provider signClearText:oauthBaseString withSecret:oauthEncodedKey];
NSString *oauthEncodedSignature = [self urlEncode:oauthSignature];

// prepare request
NSString *oauthHeader = @"OAuth ";
oauthHeader = [oauthHeader stringByAppendingFormat:@"oauth_consumer_key=\"%@\"",oauthConsumerKey];
oauthHeader = [oauthHeader stringByAppendingFormat:@",oauth_token=\"%@\"",oauthAccessToken];
oauthHeader = [oauthHeader stringByAppendingFormat:@",oauth_signature_method=\"%@\"",oauthSignatureMethod];
oauthHeader = [oauthHeader stringByAppendingFormat:@",oauth_signature=\"%@\"",oauthEncodedSignature];
oauthHeader = [oauthHeader stringByAppendingFormat:@",oauth_timestamp=\"%d\"",oauthTimeStamp];
oauthHeader = [oauthHeader stringByAppendingFormat:@",oauth_nonce=\"%@\"",oauthNonce];
oauthHeader = [oauthHeader stringByAppendingFormat:@",oauth_version=\"1.0\""];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[request setValue:oauthHeader forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
```

When I look at the http response code I get a 500. I've reached out to the service provider regarding the unexpected 500 response.

In the meanwhile, does anything stand out to you on what I'm possibly doing wrong?

Even just pointing me to some working sample code would be highly appreciated. I've read a lot of stuff out there, but I'm obviously getting some nuance wrong in obj-c. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I were you I would check out the source code of [ShareKit](http://getsharekit.com/) on [github](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit), which integrates with many OAuth web services. I believe it uses [OAuthConsumer](http://code.google.com/p/oauthconsumer/) which may be of particular use to you. OAuthConsumer has some documentation and you might want to try integrating it into your application.

If you take a look at [OAMutableURLRequest](https://github.com/jdg/oauthconsumer/blob/master/OAMutableURLRequest.m), you can see how OAuthConsumer creates requests. I don't see any big differences in the way your headers are setup, except that they have a `realm` header. My suggestion would be to try and use OAuthConsumer to make the request and see if it works. If it doesn't work with OAuthConsumer then I would imagine the problem lays elsewhere (maybe on the server?).

Comment: It shouldn't matter which web service I'm interacting with, correct? I'm simply trying to retrieve (`GET`) a URL that is OAuth protected, so I'm trying to sign the request. Please let me know if I'm totally misunderstanding OAuth. Thanks for the response.

Comment: no, in general it should not matter what oauth service you are interacting with. i updated my answer with a new link.

Comment: I ended up using jdg's version of OAuthConsumer (https://github.com/jdg/oauthconsumer/), which got me what I needed. I'll mark your answer as the correct one, congrats!

Comment: glad I could help you out, don't forget to award the bounty

Comment: Didn't realize I had to award the bounty in addition to marking the correct answer! Close one.. :)

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I've played around with OAuth, but I've made a small project for PHP and Objective-C that removed ALL my needs to ever messing around with it again.

My guess would be that your header fields need to be ordered by the field name, so, the order should be like this:

```
NSString *oauthHeader = @"OAuth ";
oauthHeader = [oauthHeader stringByAppendingFormat:@"oauth_consumer_key=\"%@\"",oauthConsumerKey];
oauthHeader = [oauthHeader stringByAppendingFormat:@",oauth_nonce=\"%@\"",oauthNonce];
oauthHeader = [oauthHeader stringByAppendingFormat:@",oauth_timestamp=\"%d\"",oauthTimeStamp];
oauthHeader = [oauthHeader stringByAppendingFormat:@",oauth_token=\"%@\"",oauthAccessToken];
oauthHeader = [oauthHeader stringByAppendingFormat:@",oauth_signature=\"%@\"",oauthEncodedSignature];
oauthHeader = [oauthHeader stringByAppendingFormat:@",oauth_signature_method=\"%@\"",oauthSignatureMethod];
oauthHeader = [oauthHeader stringByAppendingFormat:@",oauth_version=\"1.0\""];
```

Please, feel free to take a look in my [uOAuth (micro-OAuth) project](https://gitorious.org/uoauth/uoauth-objc) source in Gitorious for Objective-C (there's also a PHP version around, if you want to take a look as well).

If you need any more clarification, I'm happy to edit the question or answer to your comment.

Kudos!

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a try when I get back. Per your "ordered by field name", shouldn't `oauth_timestamp` and `oauth_token` be placed below the `oauth_signature` and `oauth_signature_method`? Thanks for the response.

Comment: I tried both (your ordering and the ordering in my comment above) and both still failed.

Answer (score 1):

I had an issue including header fields so I got rid of them by including all the parameters as url encoded. I did the following.

- Use OAuthConsumer-iphone twitter app
  http://code.google.com/p/oauthconsumer-iphone/
- Goto -(void)prepare under OADataFetcher.m, get rid of oauthheader and include all the parameters as url parameters by doing [request setParameters:[(NSArray *)allParameters urlEncoded]];
- Rest should be straightforward.
- So in total all the files you will be concentrating are oauthTwitterAppViewController, OAMutableURLRequest, OADataFetcher, AuthorizeWebViewController.

It took me almost a week to sync up with the Service provider to get this working. But if you have all the sources ready, then probably you might need 2 days may be.

Answer (score 0):

I saw your code and after watching some other questions on this website, I finally build a running code.
In my case, I use AFHTTPClient to initiate the request, I just use OAMutableURLRequest to create the Authorization header, then I use the Authorization header to attach to request that I send to the server.

I share my code here for those who need it.

In your case, I think you should check the request send to the server, and use Fiddler to compose a test request to debug your service.

Sorry for my bad english :p.

```
NSDictionary * jsonDic;
__block NSString *responsebody = @"";
OAConsumer *consumer = [[OAConsumer alloc] initWithKey:@"123"
                                                secret:@"456"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://MyServiceURL/MyServiceFunction"];

OAMutableURLRequest *request = [[OAMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url
                                                               consumer:consumer
                                                                  token:nil
                                                                  realm:nil
                                                      signatureProvider:nil];
[request prepare];

NSString *oauthHeader = @"OAuth ";
oauthHeader = [oauthHeader stringByAppendingFormat:@"oauth_consumer_key=\"%@\"",@"123"];
oauthHeader = [oauthHeader stringByAppendingFormat:@",oauth_token=\"%@\"",@""];
oauthHeader = [oauthHeader stringByAppendingFormat:@",oauth_signature_method=\"%@\"",@"HMAC-SHA1"];
oauthHeader = [oauthHeader stringByAppendingFormat:@",oauth_signature=\"%@\"",encodeToPercentEscapeString(request.signature)];
oauthHeader = [oauthHeader stringByAppendingFormat:@",oauth_timestamp=\"%ld\"", (time_t) [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]];
oauthHeader = [oauthHeader stringByAppendingFormat:@",oauth_nonce=\"%@\"",request.nonce];
oauthHeader = [oauthHeader stringByAppendingFormat:@",oauth_version=\"1.0\""];
//NSLog(@"oauthHeader: %@", oauthHeader);

[AFNetworkActivityIndicatorManager sharedManager].enabled = YES;

NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://MyServiceURL"];
AFHTTPClient* client = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:baseURL];
[client setParameterEncoding:AFJSONParameterEncoding];
[client setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:RKMIMETypeJSON];
[client setDefaultHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"application/json"];
[client setDefaultHeader:@"Authorization" value:oauthHeader];

NSDictionary *finalDict = @{@"user":@{@"id":@"001"}};
// create a JSON string from your NSDictionary
NSError *error;
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:finalDict options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];

[client postPath:@"/MyServiceFunction"
      parameters:finalDict
         success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation  *operation, id JSON) {
             responsebody = operation.responseString;
             jsonDic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[responsebody dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:nil];
         }
         failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation  *operation, NSError *error) {
             NSLog(@"Hit error: %@", error);
         }];
```

And

```
NSString* encodeToPercentEscapeString(NSString *string) {
return (NSString *)
CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL,
                                        (CFStringRef) string,
                                        NULL,
                                        (CFStringRef) @"!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]",
                                        kCFStringEncodingUTF8));}
```